# Why does char array insert trailing characters when converting to string in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to write a quick category on NSString to base64 encode the string's contents. Everything seems okay, except for extra characters showing up on the trailing end of the generated string. Can anybody explain why the following code produces the output below?

Source:

```
const char base64CharSet[64] = {
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
    'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
    'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
    'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
    'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
    'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
    'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
    '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'
};

const char *input = "Hello, World!";

int length = strlen(input);
int outlen = (length / 3) * 4;
int modlen = length % 3;
int rawlen = length - modlen;

if (modlen != 0)
    outlen += 4;

char output[outlen];

char inbuf[3], outbuf[4];
int inpos = 0, outpos = 0;

for (outpos = 0, inpos = 0; inpos < rawlen; inpos += 3) {
    for (int i = 0; i <  3; i++) {
        int j = inpos + i;
        inbuf[i] = j < length ? input[j] : 0;
    }

    outbuf[0] =  (inbuf[0] & 0xFC) >> 2;
    outbuf[1] = ((inbuf[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((inbuf[1] & 0xF0) >> 4);
    outbuf[2] = ((inbuf[1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((inbuf[2] & 0xC0) >> 6);
    outbuf[3] =  (inbuf[2] & 0x3F);

    output[outpos++] = base64CharSet[outbuf[0]];
    output[outpos++] = base64CharSet[outbuf[1]];
    output[outpos++] = base64CharSet[outbuf[2]];
    output[outpos++] = base64CharSet[outbuf[3]];
}

if (modlen > 0) {
    char modbuf[3] = {0, 0, 0};

    for (int i = 0; i < modlen; i++) {
        int j = rawlen + i;
        modbuf[i] = input[j];
    }

    outbuf[0] =  (modbuf[0] & 0xFC) >> 2;
    outbuf[1] = ((modbuf[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((modbuf[1] & 0xF0) >> 4);
    outbuf[2] = ((modbuf[1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((modbuf[2] & 0xC0) >> 6);
    outbuf[3] =  (modbuf[2] & 0x3F);

    output[outpos++] = base64CharSet[outbuf[0]];
    output[outpos++] = base64CharSet[outbuf[1]];
    output[outpos++] = modlen == 2 ? base64CharSet[outbuf[2]] : '=';
    output[outpos++] = '=';
}

NSLog(@"Input: '%s', Length: %zd", input, strlen(input));
NSLog(@"Output: '%s', Length: %zd, Expected Length: %d", output, strlen(output), outlen);
```

Output:

```
2013-03-19 14:46:51.568 Sandbox[19195:c07] Input: 'Hello, World!', Length: 13
2013-03-19 14:46:51.569 Sandbox[19195:c07] Output: 'SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==wä]', Length: 23, Expected Length: 20
```

Comment: Are you taking into account the null value that a char array puts on the end of a string? Often times this may look like a long number and you might be converting that number.

Comment: You forgot to null-terminate the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
2013-03-19 14:46:51.569 Sandbox[19195:c07] Output: 'SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==wä]', Length: 23, Expected Length: 20
```

The goober on the end is because you didn't NULL terminate the output buffer.  C strings require the character after the last character in the string to be 0 (all 0 bits, not ASCII "0" :).

---

> ... appending to a full array would raise an exception ...

Welcome to C!  The language is akin to running with scissors.   Even when you fall down, you might not get hurt.  Might not.

In this case, you aren't actually writing the NULL byte and, thus, the printing of the C string is just reading whatever happens to be on the stack after your string array.  I didn't audit the code to determine if the buffer is even of the right size.

Assuming all your math is correct, you could allocate the buffer to be one byte longer than needed for your encoding and drop the terminator there.

```
char output[outlen + 1];
output[outlen + 1] = 0;
```

Comment: Strange, I would have expected that appending to a full array would raise an exception. I guess I don't understand C arrays as well as I thought. Anyway, thanks for the tip. This line solved the problem: 

output[outpos] = '\0';